# Swift: Pass data to static table view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm starting to study Swift with the help of this Apple's guide: https://itunes.apple.com/it/book/app-development-with-swift/id1219117996

Now i am stuck on a small problem that i would like to understand how to solve, but from the guide it is not very clear.

This is the situation

[image]

It's a simple application, that show a list of emojis with a description. A tap on emoji-cell it should open the static table view and show the emoji's information.

**Result**

[image]
[image]

From the guide

> “You'll need to pass the Emoji object from EmojiTableViewController to
>   the static table view controller when a cell is tapped. Start by
>   creating a new file, and define a UITableViewController subclass
>   called "AddEditEmojiTableViewController". Remember to delete or
>   comment out any table view data source methods in the file. In
>   Main.storyboard, set the static table view's "Custom Class" to
>   "AddEditEmojiTableViewController". Add a property to the
>   AddEditEmojiTableViewController class called emoji with a type of
>   Emoji. Within the prepare(for segue:) method of
>   EmojiTableViewController, you'll check the identifier, downcast the
>   destination view controller, access the object(s) to pass, then assign
>   the properties:”

**AddEditEmojiTableViewController** file

```
import UIKit

class AddEditEmojiTableTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let emoji = emoji{
            symbolTextfield.text = emoji.symbol
            nameTextfield.text = emoji.name
            descriptionTextfield.text = emoji.description
            usageDescription.text = emoji.usage
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    var emoji: Emoji! = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var symbolTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var usageDescription: UITextField!

}
```

The **prepare** function of the **EmojiTableViewController** file, as described in the guide. *(EditEmoji is the segue from the cell to the static table view)*

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "EditEmoji" {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let emoji = emojis[indexPath.row]
        let addEditEmojiTableViewController = segue.destination
        as! AddEditEmojiTableViewController
        addEditEmojiTableViewController.emoji = emoji
    }
}
```

Kepping the prepare function in this way, when i tap on a cell i have this error-crash

```
Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' .. to 'Emoji.AddEditEmojiTableTableViewController' ....
... Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' ... to 'Emoji.AddEditEmojiTableTableViewController' ...
```

So, looking on stackoverflow, i modified the function in this way, and now it works.

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "EditEmoji"{
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let emoji = emojis[indexPath.row]
        let test1 = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let test2 = test1.topViewController as! AddEditEmojiTableTableViewController
        test2.emoji = emoji
    }
 }
```

---

So my question is: Is the guide wrong? Is the guide not updated with the latest Swift version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The guide needs to be updated**, you shouldn't have put `AddEditEmojiTableViewController` inside of a navigation controller. If you had connected the segue directly from the `EmojiTableViewController` to `AddEditEmojiTableViewController` it would have worked as expected.

In your first example the `segue.destination` is a `UINavigationController, which has nothing to do with the`AddEditEmojiTableViewController`class. So force casting`segue.destination`to`AddEditEmojiTableViewController` will always fail.

In the second snippet the destination of your code, it works, since following the tree of view controllers: `test1` is the navigation controller, and its root vc is `test2` which is `AddEditEmojiTableViewController`.

Comment: I believe to have done as described in the guide.. this is the storyboard of the guide [https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g0D5Dz_zTbpAQR3CNwZgDL8vRB0FlljF](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1g0D5Dz_zTbpAQR3CNwZgDL8vRB0FlljF)

Comment: @WhiteLine apparently there is a difference between what the guide says and the illustration. The explanation of why things work, or shouldn't work, is given in detail in the answer.

Comment: According to you, the problem is therefore to have inserted the **static table view** in a **navigation controller**?

Comment: yes since the desitination of the segue in your setup is uinavigation controller and not a `AddEditEmojiTableViewController`

Comment: PS: if you want to see this part of the guide, it's start at page 623
PS2: (thanks for the various information)

Comment: Like you've said, the guide needs to be updated. And you're most welcome!

Comment: Hey!! I found a way for use the original prepare function! I simply modified the segue (EditEmoji) in this way : [https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TV3RcFIzQkucy6G-aALj9UeYchc1SOku](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TV3RcFIzQkucy6G-aALj9UeYchc1SOku) (the selected one)

Comment: @WhiteLine That's one way of doing things too. I hope the concept of a segue and its destination is clearer for you by now. Have fun coding!

Answer (score 0):

Without looking to the guide if the desintation VC in IB is inserted inside a navigationController then it's incorrect and you'right to use

```
let addEditEmojiTableViewController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
```

but if you edited it then vice versa